# Get data out of foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach

I need to try and get `string itemOUT` out of a foreach loop. How can I achieve this? I tried refactoring to a method with no success.

```
var modalTypeItemData = modalGpData.Descendants(occ + "ItemData")
                        .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("ItemOID") == "I_TABLE_MODAL_TYPE_TABLE")
                        .Select(_ => _.Attribute("Value").Value);
foreach (var modaltypeitem in modalTypeItemData)
{
    row["Modality Type"] = modaltypeitem;
    string itemOUT = modaltypeitem;
}
```

Comment: Instantiate `itemOUT` before the foreach loop, then give it the value inside the loop. Did you write this code? Why are you using an underscore as a LINQ variable?

Comment: Put variable declaretion out of foreach loop

Comment: Do you need to get out each `itemOUT` or just the last one?

Comment: *how* do you want to save this? Given that it is in a `foreach`, you could have a number of `String`s.

Comment: Next time, use string.equals to compare string

Comment: @HungPV *no* - in C# it's safe (and common practice) to use == for string comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `itemOUT` out of the loop with this code:

```
string itemOUT = null;
foreach (var modaltypeitem in modalTypeItemData)
{
    row["Modality Type"] = modaltypeitem;
    itemOUT = modaltypeitem;
}
```

But this will only give you the modal type item of the *last* element. I'm not sure if this is what you need.

If you need all items, you need a `List<string>` or an array (`string[]`). This could be done with:

```
var itemsOUT = modalTypeItemData.Select(item => item.modaltypeitem).ToList();
```